# How to export loaded object to another script in the asynchronous function in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, three.js

So I'm having trouble adding objects to the scene in THREE.js. My project structure looks something like this:

- main.js
- object.js

In object.js I upload a 3D model of the object using loader. Then I want to export it to main.js and add it to scene there. But since downloading the file takes some time, I can't use the export keyword in the asynchronous function. Is it possible to somehow get around this?

Comment: If you're using one of Three.js loaders, they all have an `onLoaded` callback function, so you'll know when the object has finished loading. [Check the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=gltf#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader).

Comment: I know about them, but the problem is that I can't export something from an asynchronous function (loader.onLoad) to another script.

Comment: you can call a function loader.onLoad with parameters required for another script to be called